# Email of Appreciation in CV

Tags: cv

I sent a proposal for public sector transformation to the Ministry of Economy  and received a reply from the Federal Minister, who highly appreciated my suggestions. I would like to know this: can I put "Email of Appreciation" by the Federal Minister of Economy in my CV?

Comment: I can't tell if you are being serious or a coyly humorist, and I venture that I am not the only one who questions your question ;)

Answer (score 37):

"Thank you, I appreciate your suggestions" can mean anything from a true and deep appreciation to "I am politely throwing your work in the trash."

As such, I would strongly advise against including it in a CV, as it will essentially be meaningless padding.

Comment: I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, a CV should tell about qualifications and accomplishments. Most people can show a piece of paper to guarantee the formal qualifications, a degree or similar, but it is much harder with informal qualifications or accomplishments which did not result in a visible product: Essentially you could be lying through your teeth! This is why you usually have letters of recommendation, to let other people verify your accomplishments and informal qualifications.

Ask yourself the following question: Does the letter do any of the above? Is it an accomplishment in itself to receive such a letter? Do the minister know the nature of your work? If yes, then you should describe how the letter is relevant to the CV, if no, leave it out.

Personally I highly doubt that it is relevant.